# Return boto3 iam users from function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam')
users = client.list_users()

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    for user in users['Users']:
      print("UserName: {0}\nUserID: {1}\nARN: {2}\nCreatedOn: {3}\n\n"
       .format(user['UserName'], user['UserId'], user['Arn'], user['CreateDate']))
```

from this code i have got IAM users list but it prints in the function log not in the response and the response is null i want to get the output in the api endpoint but it is showing null

and i used return in place of print and it list only one iam user
can anyone please give me the code for this
and i am very much new to the coding and i dont know any fundamentals of python

Comment: If the question is about Python lambdas, #aws-lambda tag seems to be misleading

Comment: i used it because python code is running in the aws lambda function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want the function `lambda_handler` to return a list where each element represents an IAM user. There is a few ways to do this. A suggestion that looks like you code as much as possible is a for loop that creates a dictionary with `"UserName"`, `"UserId"` etc. as keys and the dictionary values equals each users information:

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam')
users = client.list_users()

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    users_list = []
    for user in users['Users']:
        user_dict = {"UserName": user['UserName'], "UserId": user['UserId'], 
                     "Arn": user['Arn'], "CreateDate": user['CreateDate']}
        users_list.append(user_dict)

    return users_list
```

After completing the for loop the list `users` should contain dictionaries of all users and the function should simply return that object. Another option of course is to create tuples instead of dictionaries:

```py
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    users_list = []
    for user in users['Users']:
        user_tuple = (user['UserName'], user['UserId'], 
                     user['Arn'], user['CreateDate'])
        users_list.append(user_tuple)

    return users_list
```

You could also cram this into a list-comprehension (to keep it short) but in my opinion this is a bit unreadable since the tuple is rather long:

```py
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    users_list = [(u['UserName'], u['UserId'], u['Arn'], u['CreateDate']) for u in users['Users']]
    
    return users_list
```

Comment: hello sir this code is showing this error
what should i do???

{
  "errorMessage": "list indices must be integers or slices, not str",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    for user in users['Users']:\n"
  ]
}

Comment: @shrey Sorry seems like I did not think my variable-naming through. The previous code overwrote the variable `users` containing `client.list_users()`. I updated the code!

Comment: ```thank you sir i just added this to your code and i got it -

return json.dumps(users_list, default=str)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iam')
users = client.list_users()

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    users_list = []
    for user in users['Users']:
        user_dict = {"UserName": user['UserName'], "UserId": user['UserId'], 
                     "Arn": user['Arn'], "CreateDate": user['CreateDate']}
        users_list.append(user_dict)

    return json.dumps(users_list, default=str,)
```